# Definite integral calculation in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, .net, performance

How do I better calculate the definite integral? I am using a function to integrate and another to find the factorial recursively.

I'l like to better the algorithm or the efficiency or even the accuracy for that matter.

```
    public static double testStatistic(double meanTreatmentSumOfSquares, double meanErrorSumOfSquares)
    {
        return (meanTreatmentSumOfSquares / meanErrorSumOfSquares);
    }

    public static double pValue(double fStatistic, int degreeNum, int degreeDenom)
    {
        double pValue = 0;
        pValue = integrate(0, fStatistic, degreeNum, degreeDenom);

        return pValue;

    }

    public static double integrate(double start, double end, int degreeFreedomT, int degreeFreedomE)
    {
        int iterations = 100000;
        double x, dist, sum = 0, sumT = 0;
        dist = (end - start) / iterations;
        for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
        {
            x = start + i * dist;
            sumT += integralFunction(x - dist / 2, degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomE);
            if (i < iterations)
            {
                sum += integralFunction(x, degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomE);
            }
        }
        sum = (dist / 6) * (integralFunction(start, degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomE) + integralFunction(end, degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomE) + 2 * sum + 4 * sumT);
        return sum;
    }

    public static double integralFunction(double x, int degreeFreedomT, int degreeFreedomE)
    {
        double temp=0;
        temp = ((Math.Pow(degreeFreedomE, degreeFreedomE / 2) * Math.Pow(degreeFreedomT, degreeFreedomT / 2)) / (factorial(degreeFreedomE / 2 - 1) * factorial(degreeFreedomT / 2 - 1))) * (factorial(((degreeFreedomT + degreeFreedomE) / 2 - 1)))*((Math.Pow(x, degreeFreedomE / 2 - 1)) / (Math.Pow((degreeFreedomT + degreeFreedomE * x), ((degreeFreedomE + degreeFreedomT) / 2))));
        return temp;
    }

    public static double factorial(double n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return 1.0;
        }
        else
        {
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is no question here, only a task. Focus on a specific part and then a specific question related to it.

Comment: Have you considered caching the factorial calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Check source code of the [GSL library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/) that is really well designed.
It includes implementations of many numerical integration algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a more advanced integral method. I'm guessing you use the rectangle rule, then there's the better approximation of the trapezoidal rule and a bunch of other methods. The better adaptive algorithms require derivatives of your function though and they get harder and harder to implement, of course. I implemented a bunch of them when I took numerical analysis, but then I used MATLAB and not C#.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Methods_for_one-dimensional_integrals